# How can I reset the Rotation of a Meta-Rig Control?

Tags: rigify

I accidentally changed the rotation of the finger control *(selected, cyan or blue color in the image*)  but now I don't have a glue how the orientation could be reset. Moving the original bone in *Edit Mode* doesn't work. How can I reset the position of this Control to point to  the same direction as the other finger controls do?

[image]

Comment: Since we don't know how you arrived there, have you tried `Alt + R`?

Comment: @iKlsR Yes, then the control moves to the right direction but the finger (deformed mesh) points downward. I know you warned me that rigify isn't for beginners.

Comment: there are several possibilities here, try seeing if a constraint is affecting it. Additionally, there should be some bone shapes on the last layer, have those been changed?

Comment: @iKlsR Thanks you, now it works Alt+R, switch tweak layer on and adjust with the finger tweak (circle shaped control). Should I remove the question or answer this for the stats?

Comment: answer! :) It might help someone else in the future, list everything that you tried etc.. or where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, here are a list of things you can go through to try and identify *or* fix the problem:

- Try clearing the rotation of the bone with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> *(this is a no brainer :)*
- Check to see if any constraints are affecting the bone
- Check to see if you have made any changes to it in edit mode
- Make sure that none of the custom bone shapes on the last layer *(this is the default location)* have been modified.
- Some of the bones have options under *Rig Main Properties* that can revert them back to their original state/position
- Check to see if any keyframes have been accidentally added.

Comment: Thanks, can I always except dashed lines or a changed color when a bone is influenced by a constrained?

Comment: @stacker I don't quite understand what you are asking..

Comment: some of you bullet points start with "Check to see.." what I wanted to know is how can I check this? Is there always a change in colors of bones or a dashed line (like in an IK chain)?

Comment: @stacker oh yes, that is one way to tell. You can also check the bone constraints panel in the properties window.

Answer (score 3):

After reseting the rotation <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> while the finger control was selected (as suggested by iKlsR) I had to enable the *Tweak Layer* (highlighted in the image) after that the finger could be repostioned by the circle shaped controls.

[image]